# VMWare Orchestrator Presentation via vSphere

Tags: action, vmware, orchestration

I working on a VM-deployment-automation project. My problem is difference of input screens between vSphere Web Client and vCO Desktop Client. Sorry my English but I have 2 screenshots about this issue:

[vCenter Orchestrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1QQb.png)

[vSphere Web Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovhqj.png)

Words are not important (they are Turkish words). First area is operating system area and the second area is os version area.
Example: if first area is "Linux", then second area is dropdown list of Linux distributions. And I use an action has script like this:

```
if (ostype == "Windows") {  
    return ["Windows 2012 R2 Standard", "Windows 10", ...];  
} 
else if (ostype == "Linux") {  
   return ["RedHat", "Suse", "Ubuntu", ...];  
} 
else {  
   throw "Unknown OS type";  
}
```

My main problem is in vSphere client. Because the version action is not working in vSphere and vSphere presents the version area as a text-box. I want present this area as a dropdown list or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so there is a bug about this. "Default value" option is fixes this bug. But this time we cannot use variable in presentation comment area. If it is not important, we can use "default value" option.

Comment: But there is a bug still. I use "os" variable at over of Operating System Version text-box. If os is Windows then Orchestrator asks for "Windows Version", if os is Linux then asks for "Linux Version". This little thing is not norking in vSphere. But it is not a big problem.